# Make ListBox transparent (a DLL solution exists in VB, why not C#?)

Tags: c#, vb.net, listbox, transparent

I need to make a listbox transparent.  I found code in VB.NET that does the trick.  However, how could I implement this in C#?

HERE IS THE VB CODE:

```
            Option Explicit
            Private Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = &H20&
            Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20)
            Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

            Public Function MakeListTransparent(ListCtl As Object) As Boolean

                On Error Resume Next
                ListCtl.BackColor = ListCtl.Parent.BackColor
                SetWindowLong ListCtl.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
                MakeListTransparent = Err.LastDllError = 0

            End Function
```

AND HERE IS MY C# ATTEMPT:

```
    public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
    public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, UInt32 dwNewLong);

    //somewhere in my form:
    listBox1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue; // <-- to see an INITIAL color
    SetWindowLong(listBox1.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT); // <-- to see if it turns TRANSPARENT
```

Am I not translating this from VB to C# correctly?  Is there a better method?  I desperately need to make a listbox transparent...

Comment: Oops... I meant "public const long WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;"

Comment: 1. You can edit your question.  2. Do you get an error?  Or does it not work as expected?  If it doesn't work, what does it to instead?

Comment: `Is there a better method?` - Yes, use WPF, which has much greater support for transparency and allows a much deeper visual customization without resorting to horrible hacks

Comment: Is this winforms of WPF?  I'm pretty both have a way to do this within the designer.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia `I'm pretty` - I couldn't tell. You SO avatar is a picture of a Dog typing in the computer.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia not really, with `winforms` you can't do such a thing just using `designer` :p

Comment: @HighCore Sorry I couldn't get all the way through my comment without taking a moment to compliment my own appearance. I am pretty sure I've done it in winforms before (without resorting to what OP is trying to do), but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Hi Guys, this is 100% winforms.  I know the benefits of WPF, but I am just not there yet, and this project is very big to start all over.

Comment: The funny this is I do not get an ERROR, it just does not do anything.  Strange, huh? :/

Comment: So... I took the VB code (as shown above), created a simple VB.NET DLL and referenced it from the C# application, and it turns the ListBox WHITE.  Not transparent. D'Oh!  Not sure why, but man this is hurting my brain. :/

Comment: How big is the learning curve, going from WinForms to WPF?  I would not mind copy and pasting all my code to reap the benefits of the WPF environment, if that is what it took.  What do you guys think?

Comment: Wow, I created a VB.NET application, loaded a ListBox onto a FORM and using the DLL set the listbox to transparent.  It turns the ListBox TRANSPARENT.  I guess it's just not meant to happen in C# for whatever reason?

Comment: I found 'C# Custom Transparent ListBox' @ pastebin.com/Gpmx1xS8 but it lacks the SelectedIndex_Changed event, which is what I need.

Comment: I do not think this is going to happen.  I spent all day researching this, and it seems that some Controls on WinForms are not meant to support transparency.  I thought I had success with "SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);" But that error'ed out too. :(

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make a listbox transparent.  Is there a better method?

I'm wondering if you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Setting the BackColor to the listBox1.Parent.BackColor and setting the borderstyle to None, all that is visible is the list of items.  Of course if you want to expose a control that's hidden by the listbox, just set the Visible property to false.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the listbox is sitting on top of a PictureBox that has an image behind it.  This is why I need transparency.